# Floating Div - Stop From Clearing / Wrapping

Tags: jquery, css, css-float

I have a series of floating divs that I want to spin to infinity in a horizontal line (continue floating). These divs need to be continued within a finite width div. Ultimately, I'd like to press divs/buttons on left and right to scroll through the items (vs. using scrollbar).

I am having trouble getting the divs to stay within their float. Once they run out of room within the parent div, they start to wrap.

Is there any way to bypass the wrapping? Once I figure that out, the next step is to use jQuery to get the horizontal to move left/right on click so it replicated horizontal scrolling.

Here is the fiddle I've done and code:

http://jsfiddle.net/stfzy/8/

HTML:

```
<div id='container'>
    <div id='arrowL'>
    </div>
    <div id='arrowR'>
    </div>
    <div class='list'>
        <div class='item'>
        </div>
        <div class='item'>
        </div>
        <div class='item'>
        </div>
        <div class='item'>
        </div>

    </div>
```

CSS:

```
#container{
width:340px;
    height:50px;
}

.list{
    background:grey;
width:300px;
    height:50px;
    float:left;
}


#arrowR{
background:yellow;
    width:20px;
    height:50px;
    float:right;
}


#arrowL{
background:yellow;
    width:20px;
    height:50px;
    float:left;
}

.item{
    background:green;
width:140px;
    height:40px;
    margin:5px;
    float:left;
}
```

Any and all help appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Actually am not understanding your question here that what exactly you are asking for

Comment: You can't use float for something like this. Use absolute positioning within a relatively positioned outer div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This, by wrapping list class inside a container with overflow:hidden. You can then use JQuery to do whatever you want with the inner div.

[Sample Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stfzy/10/)

```
#list-container {
overflow:hidden;    
width: 300px;   
}

.list{
background:grey;
min-width:700px;
float:left;
}
```

Comment: this will not gonna help ...lol ... you are hiding them instead proper formatting

Comment: he's going to use JQuery to scroll the items. So as long as the items stay in horizontal line, should be good.

Comment: @c2 that's the confusing part, if he wants a jquery solution, he has tagged wrong tags to his question , secondly even I was going to do the same thing but that doesn't help..

Comment: This is exactly what I need. I can't believe I forgot overflow:hidden. As long as these are hidden and remaining in a horizontal line, they should scroll through with jQuery (unless you guys think there is a better way?). Thanks! I will accept as soon as I try jQuery (momentarily) and ensure that they are indeed horizontally lined.